# Chart em asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Estou desenvolvendo um site em asp.net onde eu preciso fazer upload de arquivos(.mat), e receber valores em uma list para plotar gráficos de linha, com muitos pontos(cerca de 200.000 pontos) em uma única página. A questão da plotagem de gráficos pode ser resolvida utilizando o Chart Control da Microsoft, porém isso leva muito tempo(cerca de 30 segundos), o que não deveria acontecer no sistema em que estou desenvolvendo. Existe alguma outra ferramenta ou biblioteca em que eu possa utilizar, que me permita plotar gráficos de forma rápida? Eu tinha pensado na possibilidade de plotar o gráfico no momento em que eu fizer o upload do arquivo, e de alguma maneira salvar o gráfico plotado como arquivo no servidor, e na hora em que eu precisar exibir o gráfico apenas abrir este arquivo, porém não faço ideia de como posso fazer isso. Existe algum jeito de salvar um gráfico como arquivo no servidor? De preferência, quero utilizar ferramentas e bibliotecas gratuitas.

Obrigado